# Add parameters for service in Cloud Foundry manifest

Tags: cloud-foundry

I would like to push a Cloud Foundry app that needs to bind to a service that requires additional parameters. I found docs on [binding services with arbitrary parameters](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/application-binding.html#arbitrary-params-binding) using `cf bind-service` at the command line, and I've seen elsewhere how to do a simple binding using a `manifest.yml` file. However, I don't see how to add arbitrary parameters for a service binding in a manifest file. How can that be done?

The `bind-service` approach is done as:

```
cf bind-service APP_NAME SERVICE_INSTANCE -c '{"role":"read-only"}'
```

But I'd like to be able to do it in the manifest, something like the hypothetical below (but which doesn't work):

```
services:
 - service_instance:
     role: read-only
```

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to give an update on this old question as I've just bumped on the same issue and the answer nowadays is different. Things have evolved and using [cf CLI V7](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/wiki/V7-CLI-Installation-Guide) we are now able to pass in parameters for services within manifest files. Here is the syntax:

```
--- 
applications: 
- name: my-app
  services:
  - name: my-service1
    parameters: 
      foo: bar
      herp: derp
  - name: my-service2
    parameters: 
      foo: bar
```

and below is a real example:

```
---
applications:
  - name: order-service
    path: order-service/build/libs/order-service-0.0.1.jar
    services:
      - mysql
      - name: gateway
        parameters:
          routes: [{"path": "/order-service/**"}]
```

Answer (score 4):

The documentation on Cloud Foundry [application binding](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/application-binding.html#bind-with-manifest) states that arbitrary parameters are not currently supported in manifests:

> As an alternative to binding a service instance after pushing an
>   application, you can use the application manifest to bind the service
>   instance during push. As of cf CLI v6.12.1, [Arbitrary Parameters](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/application-binding.html#arbitrary-params-binding) are
>   not supported in application manifests.

Comment: related Issue for adding support for Arbitrary Parameters is https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli/issues/1173